# Cite an @incollection work with its original year different from the publication year of @collection

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex/biber to cite a collected work in a book, which is essentially a collection of previously published works. I wish to cite the original publication date of the work while indicating that it can be found in this collection. It looks like this in APA style:

Bibliography entry:

> Freud, S. (1953). The method of interpreting dreams: An analysis of a specimen dream. In J. Strachey (Ed. & Trans.), The standard edition of the complete psychological works of Sigmund Freud (Vol. 4). Retrieved from http://books.google.com/books (Original work published 1900)

and in-text citation: (Freud, 1900/1953)

My problem is that the @incollection entry doesn't have a field for its original publication year. The closest that I can get is doing something like this:

```
@incollection{naur1985programmingtheorybuilding,
  author =       {Naur, Peter},
  title =        {Programming as Theory Building},
  year =         {1985/1992}, % putting year={1985} doesn't work
  pages =        {37--48},
  crossref =     {naur1992computinghumanact},
}

@collection{naur1992computinghumanact,
  title =        {Computing, a human activity},
  author =       {Naur, Peter},
  year =         {1992},
  booktitle =    {Computing, a human activity},
  publisher =    {ACM Press},
  address=       {New York},
}
```

But biber gives me a warning:

```
WARN - legacy year field '1985/1992' in entry 'naur1985programmingtheorybuilding' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using the `note` field?

Comment: @Mico Ya, but it doesn't work the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@incollection{naur1985programmingtheorybuilding,
  author =       {Naur, Peter},
  title =        {Programming as Theory Building},
  origyear =     {1985},
  pages =        {37--48},
  crossref =     {naur1992computinghumanact},
}

@collection{naur1992computinghumanact,
  title =        {Computing, a human activity},
  author =       {Naur, Peter},
  year =         {1992},
  booktitle =    {Computing, a human activity},
  publisher =    {ACM Press},
  address=       {New York},
}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work---still showing 1992 in both citation and bibliography.

Comment: I thought this was what was wanted according to the question? I have added a screenshot of the output.

Comment: @zacque It should be noted that the image shown in this answer was produced with `style=apa,` (since you mention APA style in your question that might not have been a bad idea). The standard styles and many contributed styles, however, will ignore `origyear` by default.